# How to test RDP credentials in command line without X server installed?

Tags: linux, shell, rdp

I've been asked to test from time to time some RDP credentials, and it must be done through a linux server.

Is there any way to test some RDP credentials in command line, without a X11 server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xfreerdp is an x11 client. You could try to monitor TCP 3389 if you don't want the required x11 parts.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/187628/using-telnet-to-test-port-3389-functionality

Comment: Only testing the port is not enough, I need to test the credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I just needed to similarly test config through firewalls, credentials... so I used your tips and I managed to use it with:
xfreerdp /cert-ignore /auth-only /d:microsoft.com /u:bgates /p:Melinda4Ever /v:remotes.microsoft.com /port:3390

Answer (score 1):

Did some tests and research on my side, it can be done with freerdp, with the following command line :

```
xfreerdp --ignore-certificate --authonly -u user -p pass host
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu it would be this:

```
sudo apt-get install freerdp2-x11
xfreerdp /cert:ignore +auth-only /u:user /p:pass /v:host
```

And if you don't have a display, you can use a virtual one:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
xvfb-run -a xfreerdp /cert:ignore +auth-only /u:user /p:pass /v:host
```